# Solving inequations with too many branches

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm trying to learn how to solve inequations with too many branches.

For an example:

$3-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{x}>0$

It seems like a simple inequation, however during the solution multiple branches are created and with problems like that, I can never reach the correct solution because I get lost.

Are there any tips on how can I solve similar inequations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

First of all we need $1-4x^2\ge0\iff-1\le2x\le1$

As $x\ne0$,

$$\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}x=\dfrac{4x}{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$$  which needs to be $<3$

which is true if $x\le0$

If $x>0,$

$$\dfrac{4x}{1+\sqrt{1-4x^2}}<3\iff\left(\dfrac{4x}3-1\right)^2<1-4x^2\iff(4x-3)^2<9-36x^2$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We need $$\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}x<3$$

WLOG $2x=\sin2t$  with $-\dfrac\pi2\le2t\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\sqrt{1-4x^2}=+\cos2t$

$$\dfrac32>\dfrac{1-\cos2t}{\sin2t}=\tan t\implies t<\arctan\dfrac32$$

$$x=\sin2t<\sin\left(2\arctan\dfrac32\right)=\dfrac{2\cdot\dfrac32}{1+\left(\dfrac32\right)^2}?$$